# Decode base64 string for image

Tags: ios, base64, nsdata, decode

I have encoded string in base64 and want to decode it but getting `nil` in `NSData *decodedData`. `NSString *images` contains encoded string.

```
NSString *images = encoded string;
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:images options:0];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have unknown characters? Try passing `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` into the `options:` parameter.